# Xamarin forms invalid archive android ( no .APK files)

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild, apk, visual-studio-2022

I have tried all the suggested solutions in stack overflow. I am not getting any error while deploying or while building my solution. Build is successful each time.

I am using visual Studio 2022 (preview).

Its my .csproj config. This is the error

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

You could also solve the error by deleting obj and bin folders under main and android folders.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me using VS 2022. I exited VS, deleted the Bin and Obj folders under the Android project only, and restarted VS. Build and archive then worked successfully.

Comment: Just doing a full solution build, prior to a publish of project fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting error for (`.aab`) package format, check your `.Android.csproj` file, and make sure this entry exists:

```
 <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
```

And then follow the steps below:

1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Delete all `bin` and `obj` folders from your project
3. Start Visual Studio
4. Open your project
5. Clean Solution
6. Rebuild Solution
7. Archive android project

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can recheck your `.Android.csproj` file, and try to remove

```
 <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
```

If the problem persist, try the following method:

1.right your android project and click  `property` > `Build` > `Output path`;

2.change

```
..\bin\yourappname-android\Release\AnyCPU
```

by

```
 ..\bin\yourappname-android\AnyCPU
```

Comment: I just changed the path forth and back in Properties > Build > Output, i.e. keeping the original value, and the problem fixed for me, didn't need to use a different path.

Comment: Thanks Jessie but in my `.Android.csproj` I haven't seen anywhere that  `<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>` and I had tried that changing output path solution earlier too but had' not worked for me but this problem has been fixed now. I have done it multiple times like cleaning `obj` and `bin` then first build it in `debug` mode and then rebuild in `release` mode and the archive I am not sure how but after multiple attempts it worked.

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for your support for xamarin.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a proper solution for this issue?

Comment: Yeah I'm sitting here after half an hour baffled by my "I don't know what I did I just kept trying to archive until it worked" solution... So proud of being a xamarin.forms developer... Sometimes turning it off and on again works. Sometimes.

Comment: tried select solution-right click-archive all , worked for me once, strange issues

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ApplicationDisplayVersion and ApplicationVersion values in the csproj file and it worked. Looks like VS will not publish the same version twice, which is a good feature because I used to forget to increment the versions when developing in Xamarin.